# Glut window - menu bar in MAC OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut

is there a way to remove the menu bar items in MAC OSX, when the window was created using glut (glutCreateWindow( "title" );)?

or are there any other alternatives to create (menuless) window for OpenGL in OSX using C/C++ and glut?

Comment: What menu bar are you talking about?

Comment: the top Menu in MacOSX - File, Edit, Window

Comment: Do you want to remove/hide menu bars entirely? Or do you want to selectively remove some of the items?

Comment: Glut has nothing to do with the menu bar. But I am curious, why anybody should want this.

Comment: i would like to remove all possible menu bar items, and have a non resizable window

Answer (score 3):

glut is creating menu bar items and even keyboard shortcuts on Mac OSX (just try Command+S and you'd be surprised...). There's no easy way to remove these things without accessing Cocoa.
The GLUT source code from here shows where all that stuff is being implemented:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/glut/Introduction/Intro.html

In order to get rid of the Menus in GLUT, you have to do the following:

1. #include "Cocoa/Cocoa.h" in your main.cpp file.
2. right-click on your main.cpp file, select "Get Info", then in the "General" tab set your "File Type" to sourcecode.cpp.objcpp
3. include the Cocoa framework in your xcode project
4. add the following code after glutInit():

   ```
   if (NSApp){
       NSMenu      *menu;
       NSMenuItem  *menuItem;  

       [NSApp setMainMenu:[[NSMenu alloc] init]];

   menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
   [menu addItemWithTitle:@"About..." action:@selector(orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:) keyEquivalent:@""]; 

   menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Apple" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
   [menuItem setSubmenu:menu];
   [[NSApp mainMenu] addItem:menuItem];
   [NSApp setAppleMenu:menu];
   }
   ```

The code is by Tom de Grunt from here: http://www.degrunt.net/2010/09/22/using-nsmenu-outside-the-nib/

This will set up your application with nothing but an "About..." button within a menu with your Apps name. Just deleting the menu will cause a crash as GLUT expects a menu and has registered a callback for that.

I have search up and down the web for an answer to this and hope that this will help others that ran into the same problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm still using GLUT for a Mac App Store submission and it seems they are picky about the menu.  I need to remove the Print and Save menu items since my game doesn't use them.  I'd like to delete the File, Edit, and Windows menus since they don't do anything, how can I do this?  I'd like to keep the default application menu as it contains links for GLUT preferences, and Apple requires the Cmd+Q shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Glut has nothing to do with the menu bar. What you could do is to put the application into fullscreen with glutFullscreen() and then define several viewports in your Glut window to simulate your own windows.